# python and pyperclip issue to use clipboard

Tags: python

So the main doubt is, can pyperclip module use the text that is already in windows clipboard and use it for example to open a url like www.test.com/ + what is in clipboard? Or only can send information to the clipboard.

Or there is a easyer way to achieve this: use the information that is stored in clipboard to write a program.

Please see my code:

```
import pyperclip, webbrowser, time

pyperclip.copy('')
plus = pyperclip.paste()

url = 'http://ww.www.com/' + plus

webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems that its only possible with the tkinter module:

Must be as it follows:

```
 import webbrowser

    import tkinter as tk

    root = tk.Tk()
    # keep the window from showing
    root.withdraw()

    # read the clipboard
    x = root.clipboard_get()

    url = 'test.com' + x

    webbrowser.open_new(url)
```